# Syntax to access not-yet implemented attributes in abstract/base class, without instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I want to define a base class that implements a static method that accesses a variable to be implemented in child classes that inherit the base class *(try saying that out loud without breathing)*.

```
class BaseClass:

   #This variable will be implemented in classes that inherit from this base class
   parameters = ...

   @staticmethod
   def do_something(**args):

      #This loop below doesn't work because the `parameters` variable is not in the local scope
      #However, I don't want to instantiate the class and access it through 'self' - I need this to be a static method.
      for parameter in parameters:
          print(parameter)


class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
    #This child class implements the 'parameters' variable
    parameters = ["p1", "p2", "p3"]

class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    #This child class implements the 'parameters' variable
    parameters = ["a1", "b2", "c3"]

ChildClass1.do_something();
ChildClass2.do_something();
```

How do I get this to work (in Python 3) without relying on class instantiating and using `self`, or is this impossible?